# passing value from textbox to actionlink

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I would like to pass the value 'searchid' in actionlink

@Html.TextBox("searchid")

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "searchid" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })

Comment: It's not a good thing to put images when you can paste your code, can you please edit and paste your code ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into such the problem recently. Using Tag Helpers helped. I recommend you too.

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
   <input asp-for="Model.SearchId" type="text"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"/>
</form>
```